# Failed to use SUBSTRING in TryParse

Tags: c#, parsing, substring, tryparse

I found an error in my code, where the subtring is not work, it says "startIndex cannot be larger than the length of string"

```
 static int MyIntegerParse(string possibleInt)
    {
        int i;
        return int.TryParse(possibleInt.Substring(2), out i) ? i : 0;        
    }
```

I used the procedure here:

```
var parsed = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split(' ')     
                .Select(MyIntegerParse)
                .ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

But I don't understand why it's error because I already used the substring before and it's work, can I ask for a help here? thnaks.

sample string:

```
10192 20351 30473 40499 50449 60234 
10192 20207 30206 40203 50205 60226 
10192 20252 30312 40376 50334 60252
```

Comment: Maybe you have a filename that's really short, perhaps? Can you list some sample file names that you have?

Comment: Seems like there's a string which is shorter than 3 chars.

Comment: really short? what do you mean?

Comment: @stefan nope this is the sample of string i put it in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Substring` will fail when `possibleInt` contains fewer than two characters, so you should add that test to your code as well. I suspect that you `Split` call produces an empty string during some circumstances. This empty string is passed into your int-parser which then fails on the `Substring` call. So, you should probably do two things:

- Get rid of empty strings in the splitting
- Handle short or empty strings deliberately in your parsing code

Getting rid of empty strings is quite easy:

```
var parsed = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(MyIntegerParse)
                .ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

Adding deliberate handling of empty strings can be done like so:

```
static int MyIntegerParse(string possibleInt)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(possibleInt) || possibleInt.Length < 2)
    { 
        return 0;
    }

    int i;
    return int.TryParse(possibleInt.Substring(2), out i) ? i : 0;        
}
```

...or if you are a fan of compact and hard-to-read constructs:

```
static int MyIntegerParse(string possibleInt)
{
    int i;
    return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(possibleInt) 
        && possibleInt.Length >= 2
        && int.TryParse(possibleInt.Substring(2), out i)) ? i : 0;        
}
```

No, I have chosen to return `0` when I get strings that are too short. In your case it might make more sense to return some other value, throw an exception or use a `Debug.Assert` statement.

Comment: your code is working, but it's mean my there's a string that less than 2 char in my text file? but I already use it with the same code and it's work without any problem.

Comment: Mork: It's work amazingly, thanks a lot man, can some code tell me if there's some string is less than 2 char then the code skip it?

Comment: @Reza: the `string` class has a `Length` property (as used in my samples above): `if (someString.Length < 2) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The `possibleInt` string needs to be at least two characters long. When it isn't then you'll see the error that you've described.

Comment: it's at least 6 string. see the sample string that I used in for my code

Comment: @Reza: It isn't! If that's the error you're seeing then it's because one of the strings being passed has fewer than two characters.

Comment: yeah, you right, I just confused because I already use the code with the same text file and it's work without problem, but when I put it in different procedure like my code above, it's became a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your return statement and see if that helps you figure out what's going on:

```
Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(possibleInt) && possibleInt.Length > 2);
```

When running in Debug mode this will throw an exception if the two cases above are not met.

You could also use a [Code Contract](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) like this:

```
Contract.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(possibleInt) && possibleInt.Length > 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you are attempting to parse is not that long. From the C# Specification on [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx):

```
The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.
```

The string you are passing in either has 0 or 1 characters in it. You need to modify your code to handle such a situation.

EDIT: Additionally, you should be removing empty elements from your file using an overload of split:

```
.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires)
```

Comment: are the condition you talk is for my sample string above? it's definitely a longer string and no zero.

Comment: For example, if you call `MyIntegerParse(string.Empty);`, you'll get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because you are trying to get the substring of a string starting at an index that is greater than the length of the string.

`someString.Substring(x)` will give you the substring of `someString` starting at position x in the string, and it is zero based. You are getting this exception because in this case 2 is outside the range of the particular strings length.

Stick a try catch around it, or a breakpoint and you will see the string that is causing this exception has a length less than 3.

Comment: all my string, is longer than 2. and use the same code but a different used in my code. both of them use tryparse and substring but there's no problem, except this one.